# Number of ways to select K nodes from tree such that parent of node must be chosen if node is chosen

Tags: algorithm, tree, language-agnostic, tree-traversal

I am trying to solve this problem where I have a tree where each node can have any number of children. I have to find all possible ways to select K nodes such that any node is chosen only if it's parent is chosen.

I tried but am not able to find the solution. Can someone help me please? Basic algorithm (pseudo code) is enough.

Comment: The title of your question and your question itself are two different problems. Which is it?

Comment: @Gene Sorry about that, how about now? Is it more clear?

Answer (score 1):

We can use DFS to solve this problem. Consider each possible selection a vertex of a graph. An edge would accordingly exist between two vertices/selections, if we can transform one selection into another one by removing one vertex from the selection and add another valid tree-node to the selection. This graph is connected, thus we can traverse it by DFS.

E.g.:

```
input tree:       1              K=3
               /  |  \
              3   4   5
                /   /   \
               6   7     2

first solution (preorder traversal):
         1
      /  |
     3   4

consecutive solutions:
    removing node 3 from selection   removing node 4
         1         1                       1
         |         |  \                  /   \
         4         4   5                3     5
       /
      6
```

Since we need a start-vertex, to produce other vertices, we need a valid selection to start with. Simplest solution would be to traverse the tree preorder and select the first `K` nodes.

From that start-vertex, we can produce the entire graph on the run:
Basically each node contains a subtree from the input-tree, aka the selection. Take the selection from the node you just traverse. By removing an arbitrary leaf from the subtree represented by the selection, we gain a subtree/selection with `K - 1` nodes. This selection can be completed to `K` nodes, by adding another node to the subtree that would be a new leaf. This approach would also match the definition of edges given above.

So now we know how to produce all adjacent vertices from a given vertex/selection. The rest is just a plain DFS-traversal. Mark the the vertex as visited, get all neighboring vertices, and perform a DFS-traversal on them, until all vertices have been visited.

Comment: I need to find out all the possible ways to select such K nodes. How would plain preorder would do?

Comment: @Naman well, in that case you should state that in your question.

Comment: What would be time complexity of this solution? Because you mentioned each node is one selection. So there can be many edges in such graph and even checking visited would be O(K). Can you please elaborate your solution?

Comment: @Naman The graph only contains vertices that are valid selections, so that can't be reduced. Worst case is `O(n ^ 2)` checks, if each vertex is connected with each other vertex/solution. I can try to explain the algo a bit further - or at least try to.

Comment: That's true that it will be O(n^2) but number of selection itself would be large, possibly exponential in original graphs number of nodes, right? Although I agree I can't do better than O(#selections). Although if you can explain the algo a bit more in answer, that would be quite helpful.

Comment: @Naman give me some time, I started editing, but it's not that simple to cook this down.

Comment: Sure, thanks a lot for the help. Will look forward to your answer.

Comment: @Naman yes, the number of selections might be quite large. But `O(n ^ 2)` is the worst-case, which will only happen for a few edge-cases, like `K = 2` and a tree that has exactly 2 levels. Usually it'll rather be sth like `O(n log n)` in average. Btw I'm done w editing. I think I have an idea about another approach that might provide a better runtime, but I've gotta figure that out on my own first, and it'll sure as hell will result in quite a load of math.

Comment: True, I got your current solution. Would appreciate any further updates if you can add them. Also it might be not exactly similar to question but is there any way to approximate this value by counting number of nodes at each level? Because I am using this inside a big algorithm, and I guess it will slow down the whole thing.

Comment: @Naman I doubt that can be approximated, since the count is pretty structure-dependent, and the number of childes of each node is arbitrary. Might take me some time to get my other thought working. I'll update when I got it. Interesting problem btw.

Comment: That's true, interesting part is, I didn't find it on any competition or interview. My regular project work needed this. Initially I thought it was easy.

Comment: @Naman yeah, that's a pretty specific problem. What do you even need it for? Probably it can be reduced to some simpler problem that can be solved with less effort? The approach I'm thinking about would use DP and might even run below `O(n)`, where `n` is the size of the tree, but it's too early to promise anything for that.

Comment: True, I need it as a part for a research project I am doing on summarization of text.  It would be great help if you can add the better solution whenever you get to it.

Comment: @Naman I think I've refined the method far enough, to say it works. But it'll take a bit longer to build the final algo.

Comment: @Naman the algo should be doable. Though the complexity will rather be worse than I expected - but still better than the DFS-approach. But one part of the whole problem is mathematical optimization. And that'll get tough. The main-problem is that we've gotta analyze all subtrees up to a depth of K for a precise result. But I think I found a rough approximation as well.

Comment: @Naman I've racked my brain, but turned out my idea had a few logic flaws. I couldn't come up with anything that would be more efficient than the above. I gave it a few tries, but anything I came up only saved a bit of space with the cost of making the code entirely incomprehensible... sry